# Password_verify() returning False with correct password

Tags: php, database, mongodb

I'm trying to create a login page using PHP and MongoDB. At the time of login, I'm taking a password as `<input type="text" name="password" placeholder="Password">` and in the PHP code I'm doing validation using `password_verify` . Even though I'm entering the correct password I'm getting the incorrect password as output.

```
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
        print_r($_POST);


        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $upass = $_POST['password'];
        $criteria = array("email"=> $email);
        $query = $usercollection->findOne($criteria);
        var_dump($query);
        if(empty($query)){
            echo "Email ID is not registered.";
            echo "Either <a href='register.html'>Register</a> with the new Email ID or <a href='loginuser.html'>Login</a> with an already registered ID";
        }
        else{

            $pass = $query["password"];
                if(password_verify($upass,$pass)){
                $var = setsession($email);
                print_r($_SESSION);
                echo "Password match";

                if($var){

                    /*header("Location: home.php");*/ echo "Login success";
                }
                else{
                    echo "Some error";
                }
            }
            else{
                echo "Password not match";
                echo "You have entered a wrong password";
                echo "<br>";
                echo "Either <a href='register.html'>Register</a> with the new Email ID or <a href='loginuser.html'>Login</a> with an already registered ID";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show us how the password is stored.

Comment: Show us what password_verify does.

Comment: With String datatype.

Comment: he meant how did you store it in your database, with which function, etc..

Comment: @BudimirSkrtic https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: If I do ```echo $pass; echo $upass;``` after ```$pass = $query["password"];``` then I'm correct answers. I guess there's some issue with ```password_verify``` .

Comment: what does that mean ? do they are the same when you display them ? (`$pass` and `$upass`)

Comment: @Sanket I can pretty much guarantee the issue is not `password_verify`.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton what can be the problem then?

Comment: @Sanket Again, show us how the password is _stored_.

Comment: @Sanket - If the values match after you do echo $pass; echo $upass; that means you are not hashing your stored password.  password_verify is going to hash the upass and compare it to the unhashed value.

Comment: ```$user= array(
        'fname' => $_POST['fname'],
        'lname' => $_POST['lname'],
        'email' => $_POST['email'],
        'contactnumber' => $_POST['contactnumber'],
        'password' => ($_POST['password']),

    );```

Comment: `$user= array( 'fname' => $_POST['fname'], 'lname' => $_POST['lname'], 'email' => $_POST['email'], 'contactnumber' => $_POST['contactnumber'], 'password' => password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT) );`

Comment: Is the column where you store the password at least 60 characters? If you truncate during storage you will never be able to verify. https://www.php.net/manual/en/password.constants.php

Comment: Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: @Frankich thanks for the help. code is working now. password_hash was necessary for password_verify

Answer (score -2):

password_verify() is matching your input password against the hash stored in the database.
Make sure you save your password as hash in the database using password_hash() function

Comment: How to store the password in the hash format in MongoDB?

Comment: show the php code that saves your password in the DB.

Comment: ```if(isset($_POST['Register'])){
    $user= array(
        'fname' => $_POST['fname'],
        'lname' => $_POST['lname'],
        'email' => $_POST['email'],
        'contactnumber' => $_POST['contactnumber'],
        'password' => generate_password_hash($_POST['password']),

    );```

Comment: $hospital->patients->insertOne($user);

Comment: what does `generate_password_hash` ?

Comment: At first I only did  ```$_POST['password']```. Someone said in the comments to has the password, so I found that method for hashing. Don't know whether it is valid or not. Let me try that out. ```generate_password_hash```